# best practice regarding separation of ontology and data for SPARQL queries?

Tags: sparql, owl

I'm working on an ontology and a linked open dataset that uses it. I am using Protégé 5.5.0 on a Mac. I have tried running SPARQL queries in Protégé and I have been using stain/jena-fuseki on docker as well.

I would like to separate the ontology (contained in vocab.owl) from the data (data.ttl)

In vocab.owl, I have created classes Item and Scale. An Item has a Scale, one of 1_One, 2_Two, and 3_Three. Each Scale has a value and a label.

vocab.owl

```
@prefix tst: <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#> .
@prefix : <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl> .

<http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

tst:hasScale rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .

#################################################################
#    Data properties
#################################################################

tst:hasScale rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty .

tst:hasScaleLabel rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
               rdfs:subPropertyOf tst:hasScale .

tst:hasScaleValue rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
               rdfs:subPropertyOf tst:hasScale .

#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

tst:Item rdf:type owl:Class ;
      rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                        owl:onProperty tst:hasScale ;
                        owl:someValuesFrom tst:Scale
                      ] .

tst:Scale rdf:type owl:Class ;
       owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                             owl:oneOf ( tst:1_One
                                         tst:2_Two
                                         tst:3_Three
                                       )
                           ] .

#################################################################
#    Named Individuals
#################################################################

tst:1_One a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Scale ;
      tst:hasScaleValue "1"^^xsd:positiveInteger ;
      tst:hasScaleLabel "One"^^xsd:string .

tst:2_Two a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Scale ;
      tst:hasScaleValue "2"^^xsd:positiveInteger ;
      tst:hasScaleLabel "Two"^^xsd:string .

tst:3_Three a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Scale ;
      tst:hasScaleValue "3"^^xsd:positiveInteger ;
      tst:hasScaleLabel "Three"^^xsd:string .
```

In data.ttl, I have created 7 instances of Item, that each have an instance of Scale.

data.ttl:

```
@prefix tst: <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#> .
@prefix : <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:Item1 a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Item ;
    tst:hasScale tst:1_One .

:Item2 a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Item ;
    tst:hasScale tst:2_Two .

:Item3 a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Item ;
    tst:hasScale tst:3_Three .

:Item4 a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Item ;
    tst:hasScale tst:3_Three .

:Item5 a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Item ;
    tst:hasScale tst:3_Three .

:Item6 a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Item ;
    tst:hasScale tst:3_Three .

:Item7 a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Item ;
    tst:hasScale tst:3_Three .
```

I want to run a query that associates Items with ScaleValues.

query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX tst: <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX : <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#>

SELECT * WHERE
{
  ?item tst:hasScale ?scale .
  ?scale tst:hasScaleValue ?value .
}
ORDER BY ?scale
```

In docker stain/jena-fuseki, I load data.ttl into a dataset (21 triples) and my query above has no errors but returns no results.
(The results are similar if I use the SPARQL Query tab to execute my query in Protégé with data.ttl loaded)

If I edit my dataset in docker stain/jena-fuseki to add the following:

```
tst:1_One a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Scale ;
      tst:hasScaleValue "1"^^xsd:positiveInteger ;
      tst:hasScaleLabel "One"^^xsd:string .

tst:2_Two a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Scale ;
      tst:hasScaleValue "2"^^xsd:positiveInteger ;
      tst:hasScaleLabel "Two"^^xsd:string .

tst:3_Three a owl:NamedIndividual , tst:Scale ;
      tst:hasScaleValue "3"^^xsd:positiveInteger ;
      tst:hasScaleLabel "Three"^^xsd:string .
```

to give 33 triples, I get the following raw results for my query -- 1 entry for each of the 7 items in data.ttl (the desired results):

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "item" , "scale" , "value" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "item": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#Item1" } ,
        "scale": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#1_One" } ,
        "value": { "type": "literal" , "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger" , "value": "1" }
      } ,
      {
        "item": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#Item2" } ,
        "scale": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#2_Two" } ,
        "value": { "type": "literal" , "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger" , "value": "2" }
      } ,
      {
        "item": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#Item3" } ,
        "scale": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#3_Three" } ,
        "value": { "type": "literal" , "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger" , "value": "3" }
      } ,
      {
        "item": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#Item4" } ,
        "scale": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#3_Three" } ,
        "value": { "type": "literal" , "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger" , "value": "3" }
      } ,
      {
        "item": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#Item5" } ,
        "scale": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#3_Three" } ,
        "value": { "type": "literal" , "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger" , "value": "3" }
      } ,
      {
        "item": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#Item6" } ,
        "scale": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#3_Three" } ,
        "value": { "type": "literal" , "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger" , "value": "3" }
      } ,
      {
        "item": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#Item7" } ,
        "scale": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#3_Three" } ,
        "value": { "type": "literal" , "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger" , "value": "3" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Returning to the 21 triples in the data.ttl file, I tried the following query (with the addition of FROMs) that returned no data.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX tst: <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX : <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl#>

SELECT * 
FROM <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/vocab.owl>
FROM <http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/data.ttl>
WHERE
{
  ?s ?p ?o
}
```

Is there a way to get the desired results while maintaining the separation between vocab.owl and data.ttl?

Comment: I would argue that `tst:1_One` etc. and `tst:Scale` should be in `vocab.owl:`. You said that "it did not work". Can you elaborate on this issue?

Comment: @Stefan-broxIT-Solutions I've edited my question based on your comment. If I put tst:1_One etc. and tst:Scale in vocab.owl and only the 7 Item individual instances in data.ttl (21 triples) my query returns no results ("it did not work"). If I add the Scale individual instances (12 triples) to my dataset in docker stain/jena-fuseki, my query gives the desired results. If the separation between vocab.owl and data.ttl is correct, is my query incorrect or is my testing environment wrong, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upload both Turtle files (the data and the ontology) to Fuseki.

A potential pitfall: Fuseki doesn’t allow uploading Turtle files with the extension `.owl`. Unfortunately, it fails somewhat silently, by coloring the progress bar in red, and printing "Triples uploaded: 0".

[image: Fuseki UI: when trying to upload a Turtle file with the extension '.owl', the progress bar is colored red instead of green, and the text says that it has uploaded 0 triples]

After renaming the ontology to `vocab.ttl`, and uploading it, the first query from your question works as expected:

[image: SPARQL query result, showing 7 results/lines]

Comment: This did work! When I publish my real data, I will load the ontology triples into the dataset. But I wonder about its generality. I created a new dataset in fuseki and uploaded vocab.ttl (34 triples) and data.ttl (21 triples). The prefix statements for these files in the query tab did not have the .ttl extensions, which I added. I was then able to successfully execute my query.